# Insert 3 million rows of data from one table to other in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have one `AuditPlayers` and `AuditPlayersHistorytable` from which i want to insert data to one new table, for example table name will be Players.

In `Auditplayers` table I have a lot of players and some dates. I want to insert from `AuditPlayers` & `AuditPlayersHistory` all players with their `max(Date)` into my new table Players.

How can i do this ? Is better with batch or without?
How to do with batch?

Example of my **AuditPlayers** table:

```
PlayerId Date
1        2019-01-01
1        2019-02-01
100      2019-08-01
```

Data in new Players table should be

```
PlayerId Date
1        2019-02-01
100      2019-08-01
```

Comment: Why? Don't copy data around between the tables. Create a view instead.

Comment: I need onetime execution data script to fill data in my nee table. For new records i will use ETL process

Comment: you have one table where is another

Comment: AuditPlayers and AuditPlayersHistory have the same columns, except in History is older data for players. Players can be in both tables. I want to get for each player max date and insert in my Target table , in my case Players

Answer (score 1):

The Simple `MAX` and `GROUP BY` solve your problem

```
SELECT PlayerID, MAX(Date)Date
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Comment: It's not so simple. I am dealing with 3 million rows, plus there ate two source tables, AuditPlayers and AuditPlayersHistory. How to do this optimal?

Comment: @user2171512, Is it a Transaction database or warehouse database?

Comment: Source is Transnational, Target table is in Warehouse database

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select playerId, max(date) as date
into players
from ((select playerId, date as date
       from AuditPlayers
      ) union all
      (select playerId, date as date
       from AuditPlayersHistorytable
      )
     ) p
group by playerId;
```

You can use `insert` if `Players` already exists.